# Elasticsearch wildcard search and relevance

Tags: elasticsearch, wildcard

I am trying to implement wildcard for a suggestion dropdown. I have a few days already since I try to figure out this. :(

I have a list of restaurants (4000-7000). I want to search with wildcard in restaurant names and to display first the results where search is in front of text.

I tried to index the name field without analyzer, with ngram analyzer and many other solutions I found on the net but without luck.

Best results by now I get by with this setup:

```
settings:
  analysis: {
    analyzer: {
      default: {
        tokenizer: :keyword, 
        filter: [:lowercase]
      }
    }
  }
```

And index name field like this:

```
indexes :name, type: :string, analyzer: :default
```

**Search**: query: {wildcard: {name: '*le*'}}
**Result**: Mr. Beef on Orleans, Miller's Pub, Merlo on Maple, Le Bouchon, Les Nomades, Leonardo's Ristorante, Lem's Bar-B-Q House, Le Petit Paris, Joy Yee's Noodles - Chinatown, J. Alexander's (Lincoln Park), Indian Garden - Streeterville, Goose Island Brewpub - Wrigleyville, Tweet ... Let's Eat!, Arco de Cuchilleros, Al's #1 Italian Beef - Little Italy

I want that the results that start with '**le**' to be in front, to have a higher score. Because usually the people search for a restaurant that starts with. But I can not search without * in front because I do want also the results that contain this but with lower score in the results. For example above 'Le Colonial', 'Le Petit Paris', 'Les Nomades' should be in front.

How can I accomplish this?

The other concern I have it's performance. I know that wildcard in booth ends it's the worst case possible but I could not find any solution that gives me something ok in result with ngram or shingle.

Comment: do you mind if you use two calls???

Comment: I do not mind. It's best with one query and sort by position but any solution that works it's ok in the end. I think also searching two times. Once without wildcard in front and once wit wildcard in front. And take as much results from the first query and add more till 15 from the second. But then I can have restaurants listed twice because they can come up on both results.
I am sure that this can be done with one search in elasticsearch. This search it's a trivial suggestions dropdown.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use boost to pick the first match on top.

**Using two wildcard query**

```
curl -XPOST "http://hostname:9200/index/type/_search" -d'
{
"size": 2000,
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "should": [
            {
                "wildcard": {
                    "name": {
                        "value": "*le*"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "wildcard": {
                    "name": {
                        "value": "le*",
                        "boost": 5
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
}'
```

**Using one wildcard and one prefixquery**

```
curl -XPOST "http://hostname:9200/index/type/_search" -d'
{
"size": 2000,
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "should": [
            {
                "wildcard": {
                    "name": {
                        "value": "*le*"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "prefix": {
                    "name": {
                        "value": "le",
                        "boost": 2
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
}'
```

Comment: A thousand thanks to you. I consumed a lot of time and nerves on this with no luck. You brighten up my day. Your solution works like a charm.

Comment: I also want to thank @BlackPOP for that solution, it helped me a lot!